# I have an array and I want to change it to a multidimensional array. How can i do this?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is my array:

```
$array=["a2","a5","a7","b3","b8","b9"];
```

And i want change it to:

```
$result=["a"=>[2,5,7],"b"=>[3,8,9];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is the format consistent? If so `foreach` and `str_split` should be able to give you what you want. If not please define parameters, also showing what you've tried would improve the question

Answer (score 1):

you can use php function substr

```
public function convertArray($array)
    {
        $new_Arr = array();
        foreach ($array as $value) {
            $new_Arr[substr($value, 0, 1)][] = substr($value, 1);
        }
        return $new_Arr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result by simply using `str_split();` the function of php.

> str_split — Convert a string to an array

```
<?php
$array = ["a2","a5","a7","b3","b8","b9"];
$issetArray = array();

foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    $string = str_split($value, 1);
    $keyArray[] = $string[0];
    if(isset($issetArray[$string[0]]))
    {
        $issetArray[$string[0]] .= ", ".$string[1];
    }
    else
    {
        $issetArray[$string[0]] = $string[1];
    }
}
print_r($issetArray);

?>
```

You can read more about `str_split()` from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

> Note: Considering the format given is consistent

Comment: thanks but i am trying to do this without built in function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = ["a2", "a5", "a7", "b3", "b8", "b9"];
$main = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {

    $str_sep = str_split($array[$i]);
    if (!in_array($str_sep[0], $main)) {
        array_push($main, $str_sep[0]);
        $main[$str_sep[0]]= $str_sep[1];
    }else{
        $main[$str_sep[0]].= ", ".$str_sep[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do this:

```
<?php
    $array = ["a2","a5","a7","b3","b8","b9"];
    $finalArr = array();
    foreach($array as $val){
        $key  = $val[0]; //as string is an array of characters
        $finalArr[$key][] = intval(strrev($val));
    }
    print_r($finalArr);
```

Check output here: https://paiza.io/projects/H2Cu89RmYBi_RDSJ_loVEw